# how to return a value from a loop?

Tags: java, loops, return-value

I have created a method which consists of many loops one inside another.i want to return a value from this method which initializes inside a for loop.how can I return this?

```
  public static String check_payment_status(String id){
    String remaining_amount;
    try {
        ResultSet courseid=dbcon().executeQuery("select course_id from student where student_id='"+id+"'");

        while(courseid.next()){
          String idcrs=courseid.getString("course_id");
          ResultSet rsfee=dbcon().executeQuery("select fee from course where course_id='"+idcrs+"'");

          while(rsfee.next()){
            int fee=rsfee.getInt("fee");
            ResultSet payments=dbcon().executeQuery("select amount from payment where student_id='"+id+"'");
            int pmnt[]=new int[30];
            int add=0;
            for(int i=0;payments.next();i++){
                pmnt[i]=payments.getInt("amount");
                add+=pmnt[i];
            }
            int rem_amout_pay=   fee-add;
            remaining_amount= Integer.toString(rem_amout_pay);
         }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return remaining_amount;    
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to return and from where ? is it remaining_amount?

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.  Bad, bad, bad.

Comment: yes...i want to return remaining_amount whenever this method is called..

Comment: Whats wrong with just typing 'return' when you want to return something. -.-

Comment: im sry.....i have no idea about using break command.can u explain it further? much appriciated @ shekhar suman

Comment: method doesnt recognize it as a return statement when it is typed inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to leave the loop once the value to return is calculated, which you can achieve by placing the return statement inside the loop :

```
public static String check_payment_status(String id)
{
    String remaining_amount = null;
    try {
        ResultSet courseid=dbcon().executeQuery("select course_id from student where student_id='"+id+"'");   
        while(courseid.next()){
            String idcrs=courseid.getString("course_id");
            ResultSet rsfee=dbcon().executeQuery("select fee from course where course_id='"+idcrs+"'");    
            while(rsfee.next()){
                int fee=rsfee.getInt("fee");
                ResultSet payments=dbcon().executeQuery("select amount from payment where student_id='"+id+"'");
                int pmnt[]=new int[30];
                int add=0;
                for(int i=0;payments.next();i++){
                    pmnt[i]=payments.getInt("amount");        
                    add+=pmnt[i];        
                }
                int rem_amout_pay = fee - add;
                return Integer.toString(rem_amout_pay);    
            }                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } 
    return remaining_amount;
}
```

Note that you still need to have a return statement at the end of your method, in case the return statement inside the loop wasn't reached.

Comment: The decision of returning null must be considered carefully. If it is guaranteed that the student exists but has no courses, a stringified zero ("0.00") is indicated. But if the student id may not be in the DB at all, a null might be better, passing the buck of handling this to the caller.

Comment: If this should calculate the sum of all fees then the loop is badly constructed and the sum should cover all courses as returned from the first query.

Comment: @ eran         thanks to ur answer.bt i didnt work.it shows a error where the last return statement is placed saying "variable ramaining_amount might not have been initialized"

Comment: @KalanaShalitha That's because you didn't initialize the ramaining_amount variable. See the first line of the method in my answer - `String remaining_amount = null;`